# O que é o parametro Order= no atributo Authorize?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

O que é o parametro `Order` no Atributo `AuthorizeAttribute` de Autorização do Asp.NET?

Como usa-lo ?

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [página do MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute_properties(v=vs.118).aspx), ela indica a ordem em que o atributo será executado, entre os *filtros* que estejam configurados no *pipeline* do MVC ([`IMvcFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imvcfilter(v=vs.118).aspx)). Se o único filtro que você tem é o `[Authorize]`, então o valor do atributo não importa. Se você tem mais de um, então ele pode definir a ordem que a lógica de autorização será executada.

Por exemplo, se você tem um filtro que loga todas as requisições para o seu controlador. Se a ordem do atributo de autorização faz com que ele seja executado antes do *logger*, então requisições rejeitadas não serão *logadas*; caso contrário elas serão logadas.